# Recurrence relations and generating functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

> **Q.** Solve the following recurrence relation with the initial conditions: $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ for $n\ge2,$ and $a_0=0,a_1=1.$

I started with $G(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n,$ and after using the given conditions obtained:

$G(x)=\dfrac x{1-x-x^2}.\tag*{}$

I'm not sure how to proceed further with it so that I can find $a_n$ explicitly. Using binomial theorem for negative exponents (namely $-1$) also won't work here as there will be an additional factor of the form $(1-x)^n$ alongside $x^n$, where $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ . So please suggest me a way out. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Use partial fraction decomposition on $G(x)$, in a similar fashion to https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler-Binet_Formula/Proof_4.

Comment: @player3236, Thank you so much. I got a clue to obtain the Fibonacci series from $\frac1{1-x-x^2}=\frac1{1-(x+x^2)}=1+(x+x^2)+(x+x^2)^2+\cdots,$ in which the coefficient of $x^n$ is basically the number of ways to obtain $n$, adding $1$'s and $2$'s. Also, this is given by the $n$th Fibonacci number.